# $A \subseteq B \cap C$ if and only if $A \subseteq B$ and $A \subseteq C$.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory, solution-verification

Is this the right way to write the proof for the question?

1. $A \subseteq B \cap C \implies A \subseteq B$ and $A \subseteq C$.

Let $x \in A$. 
Since $A \subseteq B \cap C$, $x \in B \cap C$ 
So, $x \in B$ and $x \in C$ 
Hence, proving the statement

2. $A \subseteq B$ and $A \subseteq C \implies A \subseteq B \cap C$

Let $x \in A$.
Since $A \subseteq B$, $x \in B$ 
Also since $A \subseteq C$, $x \in C$ 
Hence, proving the statement.

Comment: Your proof looks good!

Comment: Looks correct for a student...

Comment: Looks correct for a professional mathematician too.

Comment: You can prove your statement without referring to single elements. For example $B\cap C\subset B$ and $B\cap C\subset C.$ Thus if $A\subset B\cap C$ then $A\subset B$ and $A\subset C.$ Similarly if $A\subset B$ and $A\subset C$ then $A=A\cap A\subset B\cap C.$

Comment: @RyszardSzwarc That, of course, if those properties were already been proved, probably referring to the elements.